# C++ vector iterator errors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

I'm just learning how to use iterators over vectors, and I'm having some trouble with run-time errors.  Here's the section of code:

```
vector<int> nums;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) { nums.push_back(i+1); }
vector<int>::iterator it = nums.begin();

while(nums.size() > 1)
{
    //cout << *it << " ";
    it = nums.erase(it);                
    for (int i=0; i<m-1; i++)
    {
        if (it == nums.end()) 
            it = nums.begin();
        else 
            ++it;       
    }
}
```

The commented-out line gives me a "vector iterator is not dereferencable" error, which I think has to do with the iterator reaching the end, and I also get a "vector erase iterator outside range" error, though I've tried to account for that with the statement

```
if (it == nums.end()) it = nums.begin();
```

to no avail. I've also gotten some "vector iterator not incrementable" errors, which I've found have to do with using the erase function, but I used

```
it = nums.erase(it);
```

to account for the invalidated iterator, which is the only advice I could find anywhere online.

I'm trying to have the iterator sweep through the vector multiple times, erasing specific values on each pass until only one is left (the code I posted is actually looped several times).  If you guys have any suggestions to eliminate these errors or can explain where they're coming from, I'd really appreciate it :)

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: based on the fact that your in a while loop until there are no more values in the vector, I think you want to delete all elements in a vector. To do that just use `nums.clear();`

Comment: @ahenderson I think the loop ends when `num.size() == 1`

Comment: @EitanT Duh. I have no idea what its suppose to do then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use:

```
it = nums.erase(it);
```

`it` is set to the element following the erased one. If you erase the last element in `nums`, `it` would point at `nums.end()`. You don't verify that `it` is not pointing at `end()` so you get the error.

Since you didn't explain what logic you're trying to achieve, I won't dig into it. I'm just suggesting you add an iterator validation before erasing elements, that is:

```
if (it != nums.end())
    it = nums.erase(it);
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks.  I kept working on it and came up with something similar, and that did the trick.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

In that final `for` loop, you check for `it == end()`, *then* increment.  That means in some cases, `it` can be pointing to the final element (not equal to `end()`), then get incremented, so that it *is* now equal to `end()`, and that's how the next `while` iteration is started.

Add another check for `end()` with reset back to `begin()` after the for loop.

I have to add that this use of iterators is a little strange.  There's probably a better approach than repeatedly incrementing m.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, that took care of a problem.

m is actually what I'm trying to find, and for this problem I couldn't think of a better way than testing m=1, m=2, and so on.  Here's the problem if it's not clear...it's a bit hard to explain:

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=87